# Mongoose MongoNetworkError // connection error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with connection to mongoose. 
I'm trying to connect to mongoDB atlas and getting MongoNetworkError.

That's my code and error log.
Thank you for a help.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser =require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productRoutes = require('./api/routes/products');
const ordersRoutes = require('./api/routes/orders');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://robertRobot:robertRobot@nodeshop-shard-00-00-5oqzt.mongodb.net:27017,nodeshop-shard-00-01-5oqzt.mongodb.net:27017,nodeshop-shard-00-02-5oqzt.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=NodeShop-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true',
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
    ).then().catch(err=>{
        console.log('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        console.log(err);
    });

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req,re,next)=>{
    res.header('access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Autorisation');


if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET');
    return res.status(200).json({});
    next();
}

});

app.use('/products', productRoutes);
app.use('/orders', ordersRoutes);

app.use((req, res,next)=>{
    const error = new Error('not found');
    error.status = 404;

    next(error);
});

app.use((error, req, res, next)=>{
    res.status(error.status || 500);
    res.json({
        error: {
            message : '500 error'
        }
    });

});

module.exports = app;
```

Error log:

```
    { MongoNetworkError: connection 4 to nodeshop-shard-00-02-5oqzt.mongodb.net:27017 closed
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/robertas/Desktop/node-js/restApi/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:276:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at _handle.close (net.js:561:12)
    at TCP.done [as _onclose] (_tls_wrap.js:360:7)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Comment: Is there some reason why you are using the old style URI and not the `mongodb+srv` URI? Have you checked that you can reach the hosts from your PC or wherever the application is running?

Comment: I replaced uri to mongodb+srv but got the same error

Comment: Check your networking connections first, since that's the priorty here. A network error basically means "I can't find anything there". Usually because it's unreachable from where you are trying to reach it from.

Comment: My code was working just fine until It started showing me the same error. Any idea how to resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

Restart your MongoDB. If using Linux then try the command:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Also, just give mongo in the mongo shell and check whether it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter IP 0.0.0.0/0 to Network Access in Atlas MongoDB. It means that everyone can connect to your DB